# Magento 2 | Exclude duplicate Item ID from a collection before foreach

Tags: magento2, php, collection, products, filter

When I foreach my collection filtered by tier price, qty and customer group I get the error: "Item (Magento \ Catalog \ Model \ Product \ Interceptor) with the same ID already exists".

This is my class:

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;
class ProductCollection extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{ 

protected $_productCollectionFactory;
        
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,        
        array $data = []
    )
    {    
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;    
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

public function getProductCollectionSearch() {
        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $collection->setPageSize(3);

        $collection->getSelect()->join('catalog_product_index_price as price_index', 'e.entity_id = price_index.entity_id'); 
        $collection->getSelect()->join('catalog_product_entity_tier_price as tier', 'price_index.entity_id = tier.entity_id');

        $collection->addFinalPrice()
            ->addMinimalPrice()
            ->getSelect()
            ->where('tier.all_groups = 0')
            ->where('tier.qty = 1000')
            ->where('tier.value <= 0.20');

        return $collection;
    }
}
```

This problem arises when I try to foreach product in my phtml file.
This is my phtml file:

```
<?php
$blockProductColl = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('\Vendor\Module\Block\ProductCollection');
$collectionSearch = $blockProductColl->getProductCollectionSearch();

$count=0;

//echo $collectionSearch->getSize();
foreach($collectionSearch as $itemSearch){
    echo $itemSearch->getSku().'<br/>';
    $count++;
}
?>
```

Is there a way to exclude duplicate Item IDs before foreaching the collection?
Thanks!

**SOLUTION:**

```
public function getProductCollectionSearch() {
        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4);
        //$collection->setPageSize(10);
        
        $joinConditions = 'e.entity_id = tier.entity_id';
        $collection->getSelect()->join(
             'catalog_product_entity_tier_price as tier',
             $joinConditions
            ) 
              ->where('tier.customer_group_id = 0')
              ->where('tier.qty = 1000')
              ->where('tier.value <= 0.10')
              ->where('tier.website_id = 0');
         return $collection;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please add

> ```
>        ->where('tier.website_id = 0');
> ```

Comment: or you can check here https://www.rscoder.com/2019/12/18/magento-2-how-to-resolve-item-with-the-same-id-id-already-exists-error/

Comment: Man i tried to add ->where('tier.website_id = 0'); but issue remain. I don't know whether to try the module you suggested because my collection, if I don't join the table, works correctly. Can I do it any other way in your opinion? Thx

Comment: Man, i tried in this moment and now works! works! works! Thans for the help! I updated my code for the final solution ;)

Comment: happy to hear it works for you :)

Comment: One last questione please: If i set for example ->where('tier.qty = 50500') and this qty not exist in my tier price quantity table, how can i make him take the amount range rounded down, ie 50000 that exists in my database?

Comment: I dont think its possible through query. still please do R&D if found something related it.

Comment: Because if i set ->where('tier.qty = 50500') return error to me "item duplicate ID". For you exist another solution for remove again this issue another for this case?